# get a map with pushpin from Bing [silverlight]

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing, pushpin, point-of-interest

I tried to dvlp an applic for WP7. This applic must "ask" bing services to retrieve a map with pushpins (POI like train stations or metro stations). In my applic I want to get the pushpins collection and use it to do something else.
The matter is that I don't know how to get this map from Bing Maps.
Is somebody have an idea ?

Thnks a lot,

Skil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the MSDN article on [How to: Use the Bing Maps Silverlight Control for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff941093%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

Once you have a map you can add pushpins where you require them.

You could use the [SearchServiceClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980960.aspx) to find nearby stations, etc.

Comment: Yes Ok, I already find this information. but what I want is that Bing do this work for me and provide me a map with those pushpins...
Is it possible ?

Comment: Your question didn't include anyu information about what you had already done or what you had tried. That is why I provided generic information. Bing provides the pieces for you to put together as you wish. This way you can fully customise the experience of using your application. If you just wanted whatever the bing maps app does your users could just go there instead.

Comment: In fact I get the GPS position of the phone and I want to ask Bing to give me a map with POI (like stations, cinema, ...) around my position. POI depends of the user's choice (just a listbox or sth like that, idk yet)

Comment: You need to query a different service as Matt pointed out to get the POI around the user's area of interest/current location. Once you have a list of POI's to show, set the pushpins on the map accordingly and display the map.